# Java arithmetics for calculating a percentage

Tags: java, math

I have a little problem in my java application.

I have to calculate the score they have when they finish, I use this method:

```
public Float ScoreProcent(int questions, int correct){
    Float x = new Float(questions);
    Float y = new Float(correct);

    Float num = (float) (100 / questions * correct);
    return num;
}
```

However, when I have 38 questions and 38 are correct it displays 76.

Comment: FYI use `double` instead of a `float`. 
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=261

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, you shouldn't be using `Float` all over the place - you want `float`; there's no need to be boxing here.

Secondly, you're not using `x` and `y` at all.

Thirdly, I'd say the way you're expressing the equation is at the least confusing. It's *possible* that just changing to `x` and `y` would be fine, but I wouldn't - I'd change the whole way you're expressing yourself.

Fourthly, you're violating Java naming conventions by writing a method name in PascalCase. You've also got a spelling mistake.

Fixing all of these, you'd end with with something like:

```
public static float getPercentageCorrect(int questions, int correct) {
    float proportionCorrect = ((float) correct) / ((float) questions);
    return proportionCorrect * 100;
}
```

I'd actually generalize this - it's not specific to "correct answers", so can be used for anything where it's some score out of a total:

```
/**
 * Returns a proportion (n out of a total) as a percentage, in a float.
 */
public static float getPercentage(int n, int total) {
    float proportion = ((float) n) / ((float) total);
    return proportion * 100;
}
```

As noted in comments, this *could* be written as:

```
float proportion = (float) n / total;
```

... but then you need to know the precedence rules to validate it. I've included both casts explicitly to make it clear that I want to convert each operand to `float` *before* the division.

Comment: Hi Jon I don't quite understand the concept of boxing. Any suggested reading? +1 for the 4 very valid points.

Comment: The second cast is useless (except for readability maybe). You may use `float proportionCorrect = (float) correct / questions;`

Comment: @Marko: `Float` is the wrapper type. `float` is a primitive type. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Comment: @dystroy: True, although I'd rather be explicit. Will edit to make it clearer that I want to convert each operand.

Comment: @JonSkeet I wasn't criticizing (readability is important) just pointing to the conversion rule.

Comment: Thanks @Jon - does the same apply to C#? You can add `int`s/`string`s to a collection. In fact I don't think I've ever used `String` or `Int32` in any code I've written.

Comment: @Marko: No, it's different in C#. There aren't separate wrapper types as far as C# is concerned; boxing only occurs when converting to a reference type such as `object` or an interface (or `ValueType`, which is confusingly a reference type...)

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. I'm a .NET developer but starting to learn Java. Cheers for the pointers.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
float num = (correct * 100.0) / questions;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Float num = (float) (100 / y * x);
```

The problem is that you weren't using the float you just built before.

Alternatively I suggest this :

```
public float getScorePercent(int questions, int correct){
    return 100f * correct / questions;
}
```

It's generally advised to avoid `Float` and use `float`, except when you really need objects (that is rarely).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
num = (float) (100 * (float) correct / (float) questions);
```

or

```
num = (correct * 100.0) / questions;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
Float num = (float) ((100  * correct) / questions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Float num = (float) (100 / questions * correct);
```

It is executed in following way:

```
Float num = (float) ((100 / questions) * correct);
```

since type of `questions` and `correct` is `int`, values after decimal are not conisdered.

Now, `100 /questions = 100 / 38 = 2` and, `num = (Float)(2 * 28)` = 76.

That's what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

There are no unreasonable quesions.

You are calculating what fraction of `correct` are there among the `questions`. The mathematical way of saying this is:

```
  correct/questions
```

Now, since they can go onto decimals you need to use that `Float`s you mentioned in your code. So:

```
 (float)correct/(float)quesions
```

That is how you `cast` something to float. To get the answer in percentage(in 100) it must be multiplied by 100 which is

```
  100 * (float)correct/(float)quesions
```

And there you go :)

For proper way to get it coded listen to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I will try explain other way:

```
float hoursWorked = (float) 32.5;
final double HOURLY_RATE = 9.35;
double wages = HOURLY_RATE * hoursWorked;
final double TAX_RATE = 22; // percentage
double taxDue = TAX_RATE * wages / 100;
// to calculate using percentage need to divide by 100
System.out.print(taxDue);
```