# Strange division error in Java when calculating percentage

Tags: java

I'm getting some strange results while trying to calculate some percentages. If I have the value of 1, and the max value of 2, I should get 50% as the result (because 1 is 50% of 2), however instead I'm getting 1% as the result. Here is my code:

```
int percent = ( runningMins / goal.getGoalMins() )  * 100;
System.out.println(runningMins +", " + goal.getGoalMins() + ", progress: " + percent);
```

Result when runningMins = 1 and goal.getMins = 1:

```
1, 1, progress: 100
```

Result when runningMins = 1 and goal.getMins = 2:

```
1, 2, progress: 1
```

runningMins = 1 and goal.getMins = 4:

```
1, 4, progress: 1
```

runningMins = 1 and goal.getMins = 8:

```
1, 8, progress: 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you give the whole code?

Comment: Are these variables ints by any chance?

Comment: Use all double. And convert only if you really need it.

Comment: I would bet goal.getGoalMins() returns different values in the two calls

Comment: Looking at your code, I would expect "progress: 0", and not "progress: 1" output (because integer division makes integer result, thus 1/2==0).

Comment: `percent` should be 0. I'm confused..

Comment: @Evgeny No, `goal.getMins()` is just a getter with one line: `return goalMins`, and it is set only in the constructor and not touched again

Comment: `1/2*100` can't be `1`. Where's your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (which you should know to give at 24k rep)?

Comment: @ClickUpvote Then I assume you could provide a 10 line program to demostrate this problem? Thats all we want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try :

```
int percent = ( (float)runningMins / goal.getGoalMins() )  * 100;
```

or better yet

```
int percent = ( 100 * runningMins ) / goal.getGoalMins()
```

Because dividing integers cannot give something else then 0 or 1...

Comment: ewww float, are we that memory starved. Personally I also prefer the first one as it doesn't have the integer round down issue

Comment: But if this was the problem he should have got 0 and not 1.

Comment: I do agree (and said that in a previous comment) however, maybe he made a type when he copied/paste his code.

Comment: `int percent = Math.round( ( (float) runningMins / goal.getGoalMins() )  * 100 );` actually gives the right answer! I haven't tried the 2nd one.

Comment: @ClickUpvote Thats really weird, if that was the only problem then `1, 2, progress: 1` should have been `1, 2, progress: 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
 int percent = ( (float)(runningMins /goal.getGoalMins()) )  * 100;
```

[Java arithmetics for calculating a percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637391/java-arithmetics-for-calculating-a-percentage)

Comment: Still, won't help him, as he's getting 1 (And that's strange) and not 0.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I did get 0 when runningMins is 0, whenever runningMins > 0 I'd get 1.

Comment: @ClickUpvote Thats whats making everyone confused, because System.out.println(99/100); prints 0, as it should under the rules of integer maths

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
float percent = ( runningMins /(float) goal.getGoalMins() )  * 100;
```

Comment: @ClickUpvote change the return type of percent to float as I did