# double variables adding and then subtracting 12%

Tags: java

So i am working with a double variable. I just need help figuring out how to add them together and then take 12% from the answer.

```
public class Hello {
//c
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        first_number = 10.5;
        second_number = 20.8;
        answer = first_number + second_number;

        System.out.println("Additional Total="+ answer-12%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java arithmetics for calculating a percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637391/java-arithmetics-for-calculating-a-percentage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get 88% of the total

```
System.out.println("Additional Total = " + answer * .88);
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the sum by `(1 - 0.12)`